# vscodeで特定の拡張機能の設定をワークスペース設定に書けない

Tags: vscode, latex

vscodeのLaTeX-Workshop拡張機能の設定をユーザー設定に書くと動作するのですが、ワークスペース設定に書くと動作しません。LaTeX Workshopのgitで質問してみたのですが、アップストリームイシューの一言でクローズされてしまい、具体的になぜなのか聞くことができませんでした。どうしてなのでしょうか？

Comment: [当該のissue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1065)を見ると、再現できなかったと言われています。つまり、ワークスペース設定に書いても動作するはずということです。 “Make your sure you open the workspace (ie. the folder containing .vscode/settings.json) for these settings to be honored.” と言われているのは試してみたのでしょうか？

Comment: 試しました。フォルダ構成や、他のエクステンションが影響している可能性やエクステンションの再インストールを試してみましたが、ユーザーセッティングでしか動作しませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

vscodeは設定をコピペすると、エラーを吐くようです...
全く同じ内容を打ち込むことで解決しました
設定を保存して再読み込みなども行ったので、JSON形式の設定ファイルでこのようなことが起きるとは想定外でした

Comment: 手打ちで上手くいったということは、不正な文字が含まれていた可能性があります。思いつくものから挙げていくと、ダブルクオーテーションが "" ではなく “” になっている、スペースやカンマなどが半角文字ではなく全角文字になっている、改行コードがおかしい、ゼロ幅文字が含まれていた、などです。

Comment: ユーザー設定ではコピペしてもうまく行ったので文字コードが違ったかもですね(未確認)